# The "duplicate answer" community flag is broken

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

The "duplicate answer" flag is currently showing like this:

> `Duplicate answers: <a href='/a/17872778'>17872778</a> – Community♦ 5 hours ago`

The link isn't being coded properly.